# Keycloak Cross Realm Token Exchange

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api, token-exchange

I am new to keycloak, and I was struggling with how to initiate a token exchange request.

I have an OpenID client A configured in Realm A. My requirement is to exchange the token I received from client A, to get the token from client B configured in Realm B.

I was trying out the examples for external to internal token exchange. And I had configured client A as an oidc in Realm B and executing the below cURL:

```
curl -L -X POST ‘http://localhost:8000/auth/realms/realmB/protocol/openid-connect/token’
-H ‘Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded’
–data-urlencode ‘client_id=clientA’
–data-urlencode ‘client_secret=clientASecret’
–data-urlencode ‘subject_token=clientAToken’
–data-urlencode ‘subject_issuer=clientA-oidc’
–data-urlencode ‘audience=clientB’
–data-urlencode ‘grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange’
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: Realms are independent instances, so I would expect that cross realm token exchange won't be working.

Comment: @JanGaraj It actually works, (a bit buggy). I have a done a similar thing on the past

Comment: @JanGaraj - Can you please share a sample?

Comment: @SachinBose When I get home, what is exactly your problem?

Comment: @JanGaraj - Using the above approach am getting the below error:
`{
    "error": "unauthorized_client",
    "error_description": "INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Invalid client credentials"
}`

Comment: You should to respond to @dreamcrash ^

Comment: @SachinBose Are you able to normally login with a user? on the external realm via the internal realm ? Sometimes the error occurs from certificate issues

Comment: @JanGaraj - Apologies for tagging you wrongly!

Comment: @dreamcrash - No am not creating any users, the access type is of confidential protocol, which gives a client id and secret key for retrieving the token.

Comment: @SachinBose So it is token from an application without any user password and username right?

Comment: @dreamcrash - yes exactly

Comment: @SachinBose I have tried with username and password, I will give it a run today and give you feedback if you still need help

Comment: @dreamcrash - Thank you so much. It would be great if you cold share me a sample code, or some workaround for the same.

Comment: @SachinBose Sorry I have been super occupied with work do you still need help with this